# Use JUnit Selenium Test for testing in JMeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, jmeter

I have defined the following acceptance test scenario using selenium webdriver and junit which runs perfectly fine when executing the test with junit:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import java.util.*;

public class SuccessfulLogin {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private Map<String, Object> vars;
    JavascriptExecutor js;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void firsttest() {
        driver.get("http://localhost:9000/friendsify/login");
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(2576, 1408));
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("max@mustermann.de");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Friends")).click();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to make use of this test for testing the performance with JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

0. First of all, are you aware of [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin? Theoretically it can make your life easier.
1. Compile your test as [.jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)
2. Put it under "lib/junit" path of your JMeter installation
3. Put all it's dependencies like [selenium java library](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/) to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation
4. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
5. Your test class and method should be visible in JUnit Request sampler

More information: [How to Use JUnit With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter)

Be aware that browsers are very resource intensive, i.e. [Firefox 96 requires 1 CPU core and 2 GB of RAM](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/96.0.3/system-requirements/) so you might need a powerful machine to conduct the load tests. So maybe it worth considering using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers for load testing your application.